# Riot/JS: How to create standard HTML element dynamically (e.g., OL vs. UL) in tag

Tags: html, riot.js

Assume I have the following Riot/JS tag:

```
<my-list>
    <ol if="{this.opts.isOrdered}">
        <li><!-- extensive inner code --></li>
    </ol>
    <ul if="{!this.opts.isOrdered}">
        <li><!-- extensive inner code (same as above) --></li>
    </ul>
</my-list>
```

As you can see, the problem here is that **I have to repeat the extensive inner code**. And this is just an OL vs. UL split (i.e., two predefined options); it is easy to imagine other splits, particularly if one wants a dynamic (non-predefined) wrapper element as defined in `this.opts`.

Is there any way to solve this **without modifying the HTML created by Riot (i.e., without touching the `.innerHTML` property)**?

Answer (score 0):

As i see, you want to pass this "extensive inner code" via opts or create it dynamically. So you can do something like this:

```
<my-list>
<ol id="ol_id" if="{this.opts.isOrdered}">
    <li><!-- extensive inner code --></li>
</ol>
<ul id="ul_id" if="{!this.opts.isOrdered}">
    <li><!-- extensive inner code (same as above) --></li>
</ul>
```

And for JS part:

```
this.on('mount', function () {
if (this.opts.isOrdered) {
    var ol_el = document.getElementById("ol_id");
    var extensive_inner_element = document.createElement('<required_element_or_custom_tag>');
    ol_el.appendChild(extensive_inner_element);
}
if (!this.opts.isOrdered) {
    var ul_el = document.getElementById("ul_id");
    var extensive_inner_element = document.createElement('<required_element_or_custom_tag>');
    ul_el.appendChild(extensive_inner_element);
}});
```

Comment: And i just found interesting thing that i think will help you. It is yield tag. You can see examples of using it here http://tutorials.jenkov.com/riotjs/yield.html

Comment: Ok, this would work, but it's not quite what I imagined. Also, it would not be generalizable to arbitrary tags. I thought of something like `data-is` for standard tags (e.g., `data-is="ul"`).